# Can not scroll down further on HTML webpage

Tags: html, css, angularjs, typescript, html-table

I am not able to scroll down further on the web page I am building and I am not sure why. The web page is two separate tables that contain their own content next to each other. There is more content in the table than the size of the page but I am not able to access it because the scroll bar is stuck. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```css
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/assets/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 30%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px20px12px40px;
  border: 1pxsolid#000000;
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'graphik-bold';
  color: #424242;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'graphik-regular';
  color: #424242;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1pxsolid#424242;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'graphik-regular';
  button {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

th {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.container {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'graphik-regular';
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'graphik-regular';
  color: #424242;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1pxsolid#424242;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'graphik-regular';
  button {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

th {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.container {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'graphik-regular';
}
```

```html
<divclass="container">
  <h2> History </h2>
  <tableid="History" aria-describedby="history-data">
    <captionstyle="text-align: left; color: #003C71;">
      <b>AAAAA</b>
      </caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <thscope="col">BBBB</th>
            <thscope="col">CCCC</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbodydate="history-data">
        <tr*ngFor="let product of products">
          <td>{{product.Total}}</td>
          <td>{{product.productName}}</td>

          </tr>
          </tbody>
          </table>
          <tableid="History2" aria-describedby="history-data">
            <captionstyle="text-align: left; color: #003C71;">
              <b>DDDD</b>
              </caption>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <thscope="col">BBBB</th>
                    <thscope="col">CCCC</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbodydate="history-data">
                <tr*ngFor="let product of products">
                  <td>{{product.Total}}</td>
                  <td>{{product.productName}}</td>
                  <td>
                    <ahref="{{product.executionReportLink}}">
                      <buttonstyle="color: #FCAE00;">EEEE</button>
                        </a>
                  </td>

                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  </table>
                  </div>
```